# error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "spec" in

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I know that `yml` files are temperamental and I still struggle to figure it out. Can anyone help out here to understand what is it about my `client-deployment.yml` file that makes Kubernetes want to issue the above error?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: ldco2016/multi-client:v1.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

I got the above error running `kubectl apply -f k8s`

`k8s` being one of the folders in the project with the `yml` configuration files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure enough, everything and including the last `spec:` needed to be tabbed to the left once:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: ldco2016/multi-client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

Unfortunately, you can't tell the difference with how `yaml` is formatted when pasted here, so it would not have been an easy catch, but if you would be looking at the original file configuration you would have noticed it like I did when I looked a third time.